# How to disable user account/suspend account in Flutter project application?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Currently, I am working on a Flutter project application which is a tricycle booking system. When a user has canceled three times(equivalent to life points), the user shall not be able to use their accounts for a few days meaning their accounts are suspended for abusing the cancel functionality. How do I implement this idea/functionality wherein I am using a Realtime Database from Firebase. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can prepare a flag in the user object.. a status flag.. that indicates if the user account status is allowed or not.. and when the app starts you can check that status flag.. if it says true.. user can login.. if it says false, you can show a screen saying account denied.

Comment: Do you have example code or a guide video?

Comment: that i do not.. provide snippets of your code and i can help you.. like your user object..